# Dependency issues do not allow to upgrade

Tags: composer, 10, upgrading

I'm trying to upgrade a project to 10.2 but I should update my modules first. Running `composer update` throws this error.

```
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Problem.php:366  
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - zendframework/zend-feed[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.12.3] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require php ^5.3.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.20] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/core[9.0.10, ..., 9.0.14] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-feed[2.13.0, ..., 2.14.1] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - longwave/laminas-diactoros 2.14.1 requires php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - longwave/laminas-diactoros 2.14.2 requires php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 || ~8.2.0 -> your php version (8.3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/ckeditor_entity_link ^1.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/ckeditor_entity_link[1.3.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.2.2 requires drupal/core 10.2.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core[8.4.0, ..., 8.9.10] require symfony-cmf/routing ^1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, 1.4.1].
    - drupal/core[8.2.0, ..., 8.3.9] require symfony-cmf/routing ~1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, 1.4.1].
    - drupal/core[8.8.0, ..., 8.8.12] require zendframework/zend-feed ^2.12 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.19.0], zendframework/zend-feed[2.12.0].
    - drupal/core[9.4.15, ..., 9.5.11] require longwave/laminas-diactoros ^2.14 -> satisfiable by longwave/laminas-diactoros[2.14.1, 2.14.2].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.2.1 requires drupal/core 10.2.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/ckeditor_entity_link 1.3.0 requires drupal/core ^8 || ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.2.2].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.1.2, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.2.2].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.1.8, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.2.2].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.7.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.2.2].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.2.0 requires drupal/core 10.2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.0].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.2.0, 10.2.1, 10.2.2].
```

The *composer.json* content is the following.

```json
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "commerceguys/addressing": "^2.1",
        "composer/installers": "^2.2",
        "drupal/address": "^2.0",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
        "drupal/asset_injector": "^2.19",
        "drupal/blazy": "^2.22",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.29",
        "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^5.5",
        "drupal/bootstrap_sass": "^5.0",
        "drupal/ckeditor_entity_link": "^1.3",
        "drupal/colorbox": "^2.0",
        "drupal/colorbox_inline": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.2",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.2",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.2",
        "drupal/flexslider": "^2.0",
        "drupal/geocoder": "^4.18",
        "drupal/geofield": "^1.57",
        "drupal/geofield_map": "^3.0",
        "drupal/geolocation": "^3.12",
        "drupal/geophp": "^1.1",
        "drupal/leaflet": "^10.2",
        "drupal/redirect_after_login": "^3.0",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.10",
        "drupal/slick_lightbox": "^1.7",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^2.8",
        "drupal/taxonomy_manager": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_slideshow": "^5.0",
        "drush/drush": "^12.4",
        "geocoder-php/free-geoip-provider": "^4.5"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why these Drupal 8 dependencies are there. Could someone point me towards the solution, please?

Comment: Are you following the official upgrade guide?

Comment: There is evidence you are not.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is in the composer output:

```
drupal/ckeditor_entity_link 1.3.0 requires drupal/core ^8 || ^9
```

ckeditor entity link doesn't support drupal 10, remove it.

Comment: Removing it probably is not an option when it is installed. But with `mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient` you can make it D10 ready on the fly by adding its D10 patch from drupal.org into the patches section, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-lenient-composer-endpoint